# Cont. Uniform Dist. Problem with Independent Random Vars

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ be independent random variables with the continuous uniform distribution over $\left[0,2\right]$. Let $Z = \min\left(X_1, X_2, X_3\right)$.

Find $\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq 0.5\right)$.

I had thought this was $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 = \frac{1}{64}$, but my answer was incorrect. Could anyone help me reach the correct answer with a short explanation?

Comment: please use Latex

Comment: Hint: If the cdf of $X_i$ is denoted by $F(x)$, then the cdf of the minimum is given by $1−[1−F(x)]^n$.

Comment: @Alex Don't know Latex, feel free to help out on the edit. Got a handy FAQ section or link with the latex formatting tips?

Comment: @CODe: did you try the 'help' button?

Comment: @Alex You mean this tiny snippet here? http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex

Not helping too much.

Comment: @CODe: start with this: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Z=\min X_n$, then $P(Z \geq r)=P(X_1 \geq r)\cdot P(X_2 \geq r) \ldots P(X_n \geq r)$. Do you see why?

Comment: Ah, got it now. Thanks very much.